# Why can't we downvote comments?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, comment

Why can't we downvote comments?

Comment: Also relevant: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17364/how-does-comment-voting-and-flagging-work. Comment flags have some similarities. If a comment has a lot more flags than upvotes, it will be deleted. Also, flags and upvotes are mutually exclusive. It'd be more helpful if you explained why you wanted to downvote comments.

Comment: @Kaestur, because I'd like to chime in (by downvoting) on the recent "Question Quotas" contretemps between two high-rep posters who should know better. I want to be able to indicate, as we used to back when sci.math was worth visiting, "Take it to a room, guys."

Answer (score 11):

The request was "declined" as discussed on [*Should downvoting be allowed on comments?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3615/should-downvoting-be-allowed-on-comments) on MSO. No official reason was given. I guess this is to keep the interface simple.

I am marking it `[status-declined]` to match the current decision.

Please raise back-end issues on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ in the future.

Answer (score -4):

Because the software doesn't allow it.

Comment: Why did this get downvoted?

Comment: Perhaps someone felt it was not an answer to the intended question, "why wasn't the software designed to allow us to downvote comments?"

Comment: Isn't this the wrong forum for such a question?  Unless StackExchange becomes open-source, feature requests, or questions about the motivation for the design should go to the developers.

Comment: +1 for the snark.